# Windows 10 - desktop files dock

Tags: windows, file-management

I'm looking for an app that can create something that will always show all of my desktop files in the top right corner.

It's for that situation where you save some file to your desktop but need to minimalize all your windows and then again maximize them again.

I've tried:

- Stardock Fences
- Stardock Tiles (it is quite good but won't always work, and it's really buggy)

Comment: I don't get what you want yet. Win+R, type "Desktop" and then dock that Window somewhere like Win+Arrow? And something like this should happen automatically at login?

Comment: Hi Fires_CZ, I've submitted an edit for your question. Please let me know if it's the right interpretation :) I think what you want is like a mini-desktop in the top right corner of your screen, that is always visible, and to which you can easily drag files. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel what you looking for but in my opinion nothing is better to see your real desktop and open the file/folder you need, so why not using Windows shortcuts?
**Win+M** to minimize all open windows and do what you need; then press **Win+Shift+M** to restore all minimized windows... (or alternatively right click on taskbar and choose "**Undo minimize all windows**")

The **good news** is opening new folders doesn't disturb the arrangement of the windows that are minimized, but the **bad news** is if you press Win+M twice you will lose the arrangement and have to restore all minimized windows by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Desktop' toolbar option that is in built in Windows.

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to move the toolbar out of start panel :)

Answer (score 0):

my friend!

Have you tried the RocketDock widget on Windows 10? I use it and it works very well. There are also several others, but with this one I suppose you could solve what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you add its main features and at least a link to its homepage?

Comment: It is not exactli what I looking for. I need automatically fill it with all desktop data.